# Getting Problem while using Array value into message box

Tags: vba

I am not much into VBA but trying some code but facing some error I don't know where I am getting wrong. i hope someone help me out to solver.

I using Array in my code and store split string in to array, if I retrieve array value in to excel range its working but I want to use Array value in to msgBox I am getting error "type Miss match no 13"

here is my Code

```
        Public Sub UrlLinks()
        Dim MSX As Object
        Dim HTML As HTMLDocument
        Dim URLary, RsltArr(6, 10) As Variant
        Dim Key(9)
        Dim UrlResponse, sKey, Str As String
        Dim N As Long
        
        'Call Clear_Browser
        'On Error Resume Next
        Set MSX = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Set HTML = New HTMLDocument
        URLary = Application.Transpose(Range("A1:A10"))
        
          For N = 1 To 1
                    
                    With MSX
                        .Open "GET", URLary(N), False
                        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
                        .send
                        UrlResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
                    End With
                    
                    sKey = Split(Split(UrlResponse, "smoothing:grayscale}.icon-")(1), Chr(34) & "}.mobilesv")(0)
                    sKey = Replace$(sKey, ":before{content:""\9d", Chr$(32))
                    sKey = Replace$(sKey, Chr(34) & "}.icon", "")
                    
                    For i = 0 To 9
                        
                        Key(i) = Split(Split(sKey, "-")(i), Chr(32))
                        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0) = Key(i)
                        MsgBox Key(i) 'faccing error here
                    Next
```

Comment: @BigBen it would help if I took more time to look at it :)

Comment: `Key(i)` contains an array. You can't `Debug.Print` or `MsgBox` an array, but you can do so with one of its elements.

Comment: @BigBen  but I don't know how do with this and how to use elements..

Comment: Use `Join()` to combine the array elements into a string.